# cd - results in "-bash: cd: OLDPWD not set"

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I tried following [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal) to go back to the previous directory, but that results in "-bash cd: OLDPWD not set".

[image]

How could I do what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: `cd -` can't be the first command in the shell, you would have needed to `cd somewherelse` first so you have a thing to `cd` back to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually helped in my case was using

```
cd /
```

instead of

```
cd -
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Add an alias for **exit** to write **pwd** to a file and then read it on the next start:

```
alias exit='pwd > ~/.lwd && exit;'
test -f ~/.lwd && export OLDPWD='head -1 ~/.lwd'
```

This solved the problem for me

Answer (score 3):

When you open a new terminal the PWD is not set as the terminal opens in the /home/ directory of the user. If you change the current directory and then use this command then you will not face this problem. Actually, this is not even a problem this is how the terminal should actually behave.

Comment: This is the right answer. This is the default behaviour of bash.

Answer (score 0):

yeah.. it works for me too.

you should use
*cd /*
instead of
*cd -*
believe me it will fix the error